# findOneAndUpdate not updating value in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im new to nodejs and i was just wants to update integer in mongodb but i con't do so.
i dont understand what im doing wrong here.no matter what i try findAndUpdate only returning original document without updating it even on mongodb atlus the document is unaltered. I also tried typecasting integer value but still didn't work.

````
const id = "6606ff9e1a5c69a06612219b"
// const objid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
export const UpdateMoisture = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const moist = req.body.moisture
        const update = {$set:{"moisture":parseInt(moist)}}
        const result = await Sensor_data.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id:id},
            update,
            {
                new:true
            }
        )
        console.log(result)
        // Return the updated data
        return res.status(200).json({ result, success: true });
    } catch (error) {
        // Log and return error response
        console.error('Error while updating moisture:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Error while updating moisture data', error: error, success: false });
    }
}```
````

Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Sensordataschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    relay: {
        type: Boolean,
        default:false,
    },
    temperature:{
        type: Number,
    },
    moisture:{
        type:Number,
    }
    // Add more fields as needed for your specific use case
});

const Sensor_data = mongoose.model('sensor datas', Sensordataschema);

export default Sensor_data
```

Comment: Seems like, in your code snippet, id is not provided. Is it into request or globally defined?

Comment: Also, make sure you are comparing same date type for `_id`. e.g. **not** comparing ObjectId with String

Comment: "*no matter what i try findAndUpdate only returning original document without updating it*" this tells me your code finds the correct document but your `update` object is not correct. You can `console.log(req.body)` to make sure the body has been parsed and that it contains the `moisture` property which is not `undefined`. If that is all good then you need share your schema as it might give a better picture of what your problem could be.